Ошибка foreign key mismatch sql, возможные решения
Делаю школьный проект, для его реализации мне необходимо как то связать должников, кредиторов, пользователей, группы пользователей между собой следующим образом:
Пользователь имеет id, name, surname, email, а также список групп в которых он состоит, список людей которые должны ему и список людей которым должен он.
Так как в sql я не силен, то у меня единственная идея не работает (скрины ниже всех 5 таблиц) Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой foreign key mismatch, либо, что лучше предложить способ как все это реализовать проще, но чтобы все работало. (Если что global_connections таблица в которой связываются все остальные таблицы)
На скринах SQliteStudio
(foreign key везде указан правильно (из lenders lender_id соответствует global_connections lender_id и тд. ))






Ошибка говорит о том, что вы в реферальное поле пытаетесь вставить значение, которого нет в референсной таблице. То есть перед тем, как вставлять запись в таблицу global_connections, следует убедиться, что ВСЕ вставляемые значения присутствуют в частных таблицах. На скринах SQliteStudio Мы не лечим по фотографиям. Приведите скрипты CRЕATE TABLE, начальное содержимое таблиц в виде INSERT INTO и проблемный запрос, вызывающий ошибку. Также укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию. См. Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?, пункты 5 и 3.
